# How can I make each section the same height?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I can make each section which is called `#app`, `section2` and `section3` the same height which is the full web page 100% like demonstrated in the #app section of my site. For example, I don't want to see the text "PART 3" when I'm at `#section2` I want the height to of each section to be the equivalent of a single page.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to [achieve.](https://codepen.io/masonfox/pen/YwbpgG)

In order to make them all the same height I used the following CSS however, I'm obviously missing something as it's not working.

```
body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#app
#section2,
#section3,{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a link to my site code using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgkg3syj/2/)

Comment: remove "," from section3 style.

Comment: Your JSfiddle has `#section3` nested inside `#section2`. This will preclude the possibility of each having the same height, since `#section3` will always expand `#section2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#app,
#section2,
#section3 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Your initial CSS is improperly written so that the above code (corrected) is never properly applied.  Fix that and you're well on your way to achieving your desired results.

Comment: What a silly mistake! Thanks for your help appreciate your time.